In 1982 Admiral Grace Hopper said "I still haven't found out why helicopter rotors go the way they do". If she were here today, how might one answer?
After about 24:50 in the video NSA Releases Internal 1982 Lecture by Computing Pioneer Rear Admiral Grace Hopper Admiral Hopper says:

...Now when it comes to carousels at airports I can see a good reason why they run this way that's because most people are right-handed - that's the way you grab your bag. I still haven't found out why helicopter rotors go the way they do, but um... I find it rather
interesting that that we've always done it this way seems to be so much embedded in things. And it's the most dangerous phrase you can use in a computer installation.

Question: In 1982 Admiral Grace Hopper said "I still haven't found out why helicopter rotors go the way they do". If she were here today, how might one answer?
Is it like her example of clocks, in that they could go in either direction and it's just a convention, or based on history, or is the direction of rotation chosen for some specific reason(s)?
"Bonus points" to address if there'd be any problems with building and selling helicopters today that spun the opposite direction (other than marketing).

Her point is that in computer installation you should think about every decision and not just do things as they have "always" been done.

@PeterKämpf Indeed, I watched the video with rapt attention, and applied her message (one of many in the video) to helicopter helicity. "Is it like her example of clocks, in that they could go in either direction and it's just a convention, or based on history, or is the direction of rotation chosen for some specific reason(s)?" I would guess that each time Bell introduced a new model, they didn't choose the same helicity just because they've always done it that way, but indeed for "marketing" reasons; the training overhead and general confusion would be a barrier to entry.

@PeterKämpf while it is "the way we've always done it", there are good reasons to opt for the same helicity as previous models. I wanted to see if they went beyond backwards compatibility or not. It seems they don't.

For clocks in particular - in the northern hemisphere, if you put a pole in the ground its shadow will rotate clockwise through the day, as does the sun itself in the sky.

Interestingly today we still have no good reason for doing it one way or another. It's just mostly how it's always been done at a particular company. The problem is once you start doing things one way a lot of your parts and tooling are designed for the way you normally do things so it's hard for a company to do both. Their competitors though are free to do it the other way.

@PartyArk now how the heck does the Sun know to go clockwise?

@uhoh I think it's much easier to explain why the sun knows to go clockwise than to explain why most humans know to be born right-handed. So if "most humans are right-handed" is an example of a good reason of suitcase carousels, "sun goes clockwise where most land is" seems to be even a better reason for clocks. So its a bit weird to use clocks as an example of arbitrary convention while using carousels as an example of a convention with a reason.

@JiK I was being humorous/ironic, but I do see what you mean, if one sees sundials and mechanical clocks as both kinds of clocks. To me they are apples and oranges. There's no connection. One's mechanical, indoors, vertical, and has moving needles, the other is sculptural, outdoors, horizontal, and has no moving parts whatsoever. Since mathematical convention for rotation is counterclockwise (right hand rule, the slope of the line is measured from the x axis ccw to the y axis) I think clocks all turn the wrong way.

@uhoh, please accept my answer if it helped to find your answer ^_^

@AadirajAnil thanks for the reminder. I usually wait several weeks before accepting so as not to discourage additional answers, and the bump to the active queue that happens on accept is more effective at bringing the answer to additional readers' attention is more effective if some time has gone by. Since several weeks have indeed gone by and no additional answers have been posted, then your answer is "ripe" for accepting :-)

It's a convention and both clockwise and counterclockwise work fine because the blade can be designed for either.
The direction of rotation of helicopter rotors is somewhat standardized but varies between manufacturers. American helicopters like those made by Bell and Sikorsky have counterclockwise-rotating main rotors (from above), while a few European helicopters, like some French (Eurocopter Tiger) and Russian models (Mil Mi-8), rotate clockwise.
It's not entirely a Europe vs North America thing because some European manufacturers such as AgustaWestland AW101 and AgustaWestland A109 have counterclockwise-rotating rotors. German and Japanese manufacturers such as MBB (Germany) and Kawasaki (Japan) also have counterclockwise rotating rotors.
Historically speaking it is often attributed to the Sikorsky R4 which began this counterclockwise rotor convention. Westland in the UK and Agusta in Italy as well as the Japanese manufacturers Mitsubishi, and Kawasaki all entered the helicopter market by making licensing agreements to build American designs so this design language was carried across and is the norm now.
One more reason countries have localized standards is because the pilots would need to be retrained and use a different muscle memory for rotors spinning in different directions. I'd think this would be quite difficult.
Here's a diagram on this (LE marks leading edge) -

(Source)
So basically there's helicopters that spin the rotor in both directions, but in one place, it is more likely you'll only see one or the other.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

One or the other, or both directions on the same helicopter: see Chinooks, Kaman K-Max, etc
